# Redis key is not creating properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am new to Redis and am trying to `hmset` some values by generating my own keys to store and access it. But for some reason, key is not being created properly and the data's are overwritten. Below is my code for it,

```
locations.forEach(function(location) {
  var key = location.id;
  console.log(key); // all keys are correct
  client.hmset("locations", { key: location }); // using redis-jsonify
});
```

The data am getting is only one of the whole response since the key is actually saved as **key** itself.

For example:

[image]

I tried using `client.incr('id', function(err, id) {});` but same problem.

Need help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are your requirements, question seems to be very confusing and unclear?

Comment: There are datas that I want to save it in "locations". The `key` is used to have a unique value(i.e, id) for my each location. Problem is, instead of taking in the value, the word key itself being saved as its key name and am getting only one data. In the picture, if you see, the added locations shows as '1' where I have several.

Comment: Can you print result from reids-cli, how is your hash looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Redis HMSET doc](http://redis.io/commands/hmset):

> Sets the specified fields to their respective values in the hash
>   stored at key. This command **overwrites any existing fields** in the
>   hash. If key does not exist, a new key holding a hash is created.

HMSET is used to set all the values at once.

If you want to set one hash field at a time, use [HSET](http://redis.io/commands/hset):

```js
locations.forEach(function(location) {
  var key = location.id;
  client.hset("locations", key, location); // or `JSON.stringify(location)` if redis-jsonify doesn't work as expected
});
```

Comment: Awesome, its working. Thanks a lot. Spent my whole day on this.

Comment: @RaghavManikandan Glad it helps. Redis is worth learning it, when you want to use one command I recommend navigate a little through the related commands in the doc, you may find another one better suited for your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

`Closures` to `resuce`

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    (function(i) {
        console.log('locations: ' + location[i]);
        client.hmset("locations", { i: location[i] });
    })(i);

}
```

Comment: Still same problem. Now its **i** instead of **key** and only one data.

Comment: Yes. It throws as `locations: [object Object]`